# This is my code but I'm getting the error: TypeError: firestore.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
//OtherInfo.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DateOfBirthPicker from "./DateOfBirthPicker";
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseApp from "./firebaseConfig"; // Import the Firebase configuration

export function formatDOB(date) {
  // The formatDOB function remains the same
}

function OtherInfo({ formData, setFormData }) {
  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    // Handle the date selection here
    console.log("Selected date:", date);
    setFormData({ ...formData, dob: date }); // Save the selected date in the formData state

    // Save to Firestore
    const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp); // Pass the Firebase instance to getFirestore

    firestore
      .collection("users") // Replace "users" with the name of your collection
      .doc("dob") // Replace "userDocumentId" with the ID of the user document in Firestore, or use .add() to create a new document
      .update({ dob: formatDOB(date) }) // Format the date before saving to Firestore
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Date of Birth successfully saved to Firestore!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error saving Date of Birth to Firestore:", error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="other-info-container">
      <label htmlFor="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
      <DateOfBirthPicker // Use the DateOfBirthPicker component
        selectedDate={formData.dob}
        onDateChange={handleDateChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default OtherInfo;
```

I'm trying to add data into firebase. Its instead giving an error saying:
TypeError: firestore.collection is not a function.
Please can anyone help me in this situation?
I am using firebase as a database in this situation.

Comment: What version of firebase are you using?

Comment: I'm using firebase V10.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in version 8, firebase's api changed. Instead of the collection object having methods which you chain together, you import functions and call them.

This code...

```
firestore
  .collection("users")
  .doc("dob")
  .update({ dob: formatDOB(date) })
```

... is now done like this:

```
import { collection, doc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'

const ref = doc(collection('users'), 'dob');
updateDoc(ref, { dob: formatDOB(date) });
```

If you're looking at documentation for firestore (eg, [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) on adding data), make sure to select "Web modular api" on the examples, to see them formatted for version 8+. "Web namespaced api" shows the old style